# I have developed my application webforms separately. Now I have added Web Api MVC while calling method of controller I am getting following error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have developed my application webforms separately. Now I have added Web Api while calling method of controller I am getting following error:

> No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'List`1' from content with media type 'text/html'.

Here is my controller:

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/Announce")]
public class AnnouncementController : ApiController
{
        // GET api/<controller>
        [Route("GetData")]
        [HttpGet]
        public List<EAnnouncement> Get(string code)
        {
            return AnnouncementC.getdata(code);
        }

        [Route]
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post(EAnnouncement announcement)
        {
            AnnouncementC.insert(announcement);
        }
}
```

Here I am calling the method:

```
public static IQueryable<EAnnouncement> addressBookGrid_GetData(string code)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49540");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Announce/" + code).Result;
    //  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    List<EAnnouncement> addressBooks = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<EAnnouncement>>().Result;
    return addressBooks.AsQueryable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the content type of the request. Set the value using StringContent constructor.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49540");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders
  .Accept
  .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "RelativAaddressOfController");

request.Content = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to be correct without any issues. Not sure what's wrong. Could you add this line to your existing code and give it  a try. `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");`

Comment: Also you could add the MediaTypeFormatters in the ReadAsAsync() method     `var formatters = new List<MediaTypeFormatter>() {
    new MyCustomFormatter(),
    new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(),
    new XmlMediaTypeFormatter()
};
resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Product>>(formatters);`